# Notation for sequences and seriers

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have a sequence $\{a_n\}^\infty_1$ and define the sequence of partial sums as $\{s_n\}^\infty_1$ Where $s_n=\sum^n_{i=1} a_i$
Can someone explain to me why we can write
$\{s_n\}^\infty_1=\sum^\infty_{i=1} a_i$.
It says it’s an abbreviation of $\{s_n\}^\infty_1$ but I don’t s we how.

Comment: I don't write that: I write $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i=\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n$, provided that limit exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct expression is

$$\{s_n\}_1^\infty=\left\{\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right\}_1^\infty$$

otherwise  you are comparing a sequence and a number.

---

**Addendum:**

I would have no objection seeing

$$s_\infty=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^na_i.$$

Comment: Yes, I agree with this notation, the way it was phrased in the book was very confusing